# cbind two lists of data.frames to a new list

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, cbind

I have two lists of data.frames. Both lists have the same length and contain fitting data.frames in their according list elements.
So the scenario looks like this

```
dfa = data.frame(a=1:3, b = letters[1:3])
dfb = data.frame(x=runif(3))
a = replicate(3, dfa, simplify = FALSE)
b = replicate(3, dfb, simplify = FALSE)
```

One obvious solution is:

```
lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) cbind(a[[i]], b[[i]]))
```

But I was wondering if their might be a better solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Map`

```
Map(cbind, a, b)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mapply` :

```
mapply(cbind, a, b, SIMPLIFY=F)
```

Comment: `Map` is kind of a wrapper for `mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`  Check the `Map`